# Table not working as intended with overflow:auto using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

Here is the table I have made : [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/npp6e/1/)

At first it was working well but I wanted to add the scroll on the left because table had a lot of rows. In order to do it I have set the overflow:auto to the tbody in the CSS. It didn't work.
Then I added

```
#training_table thead, #training_table tbody {
    display:block;
}
```

After that it worked, there is a scrollbar however as you see on the link all the rows are compressed.
Now I can't make them to look correctly. 
What was my mistake?

EDIT: the head of the table shouldn't go up when scrolling. (should be always visible)

Comment: can you fix your fiddle, see only 2 rows (pitchers and batters), and the text is white.

Comment: @badZoke I have just updated and edited the link, click to it once more please

Comment: added answer please check

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display: block;` from `#training_table thead, #training_table tbody`

And add these to `#training_table`,

```
height: 200px; // or whatever your limit is
display: table-cell;
overflow-y: scroll; //as per your preference 
overflow-x: hidden; //as per your preference
```

[Test Link -- full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/npp6e/5/embedded/result/)

[Test Link -- fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/npp6e/5/)

Comment: I see, but the table head goes up when scrolling too. I need it to stay always on top even if scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following change to the css and it will work fine:
Replace `display: block;` with `display: block inline;`

Comment: Then the overflow:auto is not making effect: no scrollbar appears.

Comment: i tried this in your fiddle and its working fine there. I just updated `#training_table thead, #training_table tbody` rule.

Comment: well i don't know why you cant see the scroll bar there. By the way i tested this in chrome.